# Apparmor and libvirt - warnings and errors

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, ubuntu-22.04, apparmor

I have a fresh Debian 12 installed and updated. Along with Cockpit and Cockpit virtual machines.

I am getting the following errors and warning when looking at the log section in Cockpit:

`Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied    libvirtd`

`Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied    libvirtd`

`Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied libvirtd`

The virtual machines start up and has no issues. However, the errors pop up after every reboot once I click the virtual machines section on Cockpit. These errors only show then, and not when I do not go to virtual machines section in Cockpit. So it seems to only start once you go to that section in Cockpit.

Has anyone else experience this issue? It gives exactly the same warnings / errors on Ubuntu 22.04 as well.

Comment: you may edit the profile to add an allow read to the profile. apparmor restrict this.

Comment: @djdomi - *edit the profile to add an allow read to the profile* - I'm sure this is meaningful to you, but it's not

Comment: Profile /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd is giving access to /sys/kernel/apparmor/profiles r,. Yet, error messages still show up in log.

Comment: I know this is late to the party, but I was able to fix this on my SLES 15 SP5 machine by moving that apparmor read line above the 5 deny lines just above it. My theory is that the audit deny with globbing on the entire folder is denying the read attempt *before* the line that accepts it can approve. So by moving it earlier in the file we resolve the issue. I made the change in the usr.sbin.virtqemud and usr.sbin.libvirtd files.